# No application name appear in the PUSH Notification setting

Tags: iphone, push-notification

i am developing iphone with the push notification feature. I have tested in the development environment. But, when I released my app to the appStore. The user complaint that the app name does not appear in the notification push setting(setting preferences). I am stuck for days about this issue, please give me some guide.

And, is it possible for me to test the application for the push feature as a "real user" before i released it to the appStore?

Thanks.

andershen

Answer (score 0):

Before releasing your app in the appstore, you must test it in development with development certs.
For testing in development mode, compile your app in debug.